# Angular 2 save Excel File

Tags: asp.net, excel, angular, download

I'm trying to save a Excel File from my server to Client PC but it get all messed up.

When I request my file to the server the body of the request comes like this:

> ��ࡱ�>��   &����

I guess it's normal since excel is in binary format. I'm using file-saver plugin to save my files, at the moment I have the CSV and ASCII files working well.
This is my function to download:

```
downloadFile(filePath: string, name: string): void{
        this.dataImportService.downloadFile(filePath)
            .then(data => {
                this.headers = data.headers;
                let content = this.headers.get('content-type');
                var blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: content });
                importedSaveAs(blob, name);
            });
    }
```

Anything that I'm doing wrong or that I can improve?
Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT:** This is my server code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public void downloadFile(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

                HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

                response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
                response.AddHeader("Content-Type", Utils.MimeTypesConverter.GetMimeType(extension));

                response.TransmitFile(path);
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

        }
```

and my **dataImportService.ts**

```
downloadFile(filePath: string): any{
    return this.http.get(SERVICE_URL + 'DataImport/downloadFile?path=' + filePath)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response =>{ 
        return response;
        })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

My http response from server:

[image]

Comment: You should tag the language of your server-code BTW. Is it ASP.NET?

Comment: @JGFMK Yes, It's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149386/discussion-between-joao-silva-and-jgfmk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to map the Response which includes HTTP Headers to the Blob on it's own.
So change code to an Observable wtih a map to transform response.

```
downloadFile(filePath: string): Observable<any> { 
  return this.http.get(
  `${SERVICE_URL}DataImport/downloadFile?path=${filePath}`, 
  {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }
) 
.map(res:Response => res.blob()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the hard work you had with me! Thank you for all the help!

Comment: There were some other telltale signs. The response had a content-length of 167 bytes... way too short for the spreadsheet. When you looked at the response-header for a CSV file the thing had chunked transfer encoding.. That was originally missing in the response headers.